# Symfony2, LiipImagineBundle resize image exactly as width and height given in config

Tags: symfony, image-resizing, liipimaginebundle

I'm using LiipImagineBundle and I'd like to resize image exactly as width and height given in config

Right now , an original image **570px*251px** is resized at **75px*33px** although the size is **75px*55px** in config.

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
   default:
      web_path: ~

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    travel_75_55:
        quality: 80
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [75, 55], mode: inset }
```

LiipimagineBunde resize it sometimes 45px height, sometimes 33px height according to the height of original image I think.

How can I resize image exactly as width and height given in config ?

Comment: Are you wanting to create a background for the picture that fills the rest of the space or are you wanting the image to be 55px wide with the overlap being cut off?

Comment: No I don't want to create a background, I want image to be 55px height

Comment: With the extra cut off? Or the image stretched out of proportion to fit?

Comment: Each travel has an original image uploaded at the same time when adding a new travel. I'd like just create an small image 75*55 from  that original image. The code work fine and create the small image but the height is not correct. I'd lik it 55px but liipimagineBunde create it sometimes 45px, sometimes 33px according to the height of original image I think.I hope it is clear

Comment: Nope, that's not much clearer. There are 3 options. `A` resize the image so that it fits inside your dimensions and create a background to fill the space. `B` resize the image so that the image fills the space and the overlap is remove. `C` resize the image so that the height and width fill the pace entirely but the proportions might not be correct. Which is it that you are after?

Comment: I have replaced inset by outbound and it's fine now. thank you